# Solve $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3 + \tan x}- \sqrt{3 + \sin x}}{x(\cos 3x - \cos 2x)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Can anybody help me with this? I have tried to rationalize it and using L'Hopital but none of it works.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3 + \tan x}- \sqrt{3 + \sin x}}{x(\cos 3x - \cos 2x)}$

Sorry, I just recheck it again from the real problem, and noticed that it was a typo since it should be $+ \sin x$ not $- \sin x$

Comment: did you mean $\sqrt{3-\tan(x)}$ or $\sqrt{3+\sin(x)}$ instead?

Comment: Limit is finite if it is $+\sin x$ in the question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original question had $\sqrt{3-\sin x}$

If you rationalize, you get
\begin{multline}
\frac{\tan x+\sin x}{x(\cos3x-\cos2x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+\tan x}+\sqrt{3-\sin x}}
\\=
\frac{\sin x}{x(\cos3x-\cos2x)}\frac{1+\cos x}{\cos x(\sqrt{3+\tan x}+\sqrt{3-\sin x}\,)}
\end{multline}
The limit is infinite, because $\sin x$ “cancels out” with $x$ and the second fraction has finite limit.

So you basically remain with
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\cos3x-\cos2x}=-\infty
$$

---

You possibly have a typo and it should be $\sqrt{3+\sin x}$ in the given expression. This would lead to consider
$$
\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x(\cos3x-\cos2x)}\frac{1}{\cos x(\sqrt{3+\tan x}+\sqrt{3+\sin x}\,)}
$$
and now the limit *is* finite. We just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos3x-\cos2x}=-\frac{1}{5}
$$
so the limit would be
$$
-\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}
$$

Similarly, the limit is finite if you have $\sqrt{3-\tan x}$.

Comment: Also I would have rationalised looking immediately the title :-)

Comment: @egreg, if I have both $\sqrt{3 - \tan x}$ and $\sqrt{3 - \sin x}$, the limit would be finite, is that right?

Comment: @egreg, how could you possibly know that I do have a typo?

Comment: @WiloryLu The denominator has order $3$, so also the numerator should. With $1+\cos x$ the order is $1$; with $1-\cos x$ the order is $3$. This was the hint for spotting the typo.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, I don't know what is order, could you explain it to me? By the way, thank you so much for giving me a detailed explanation.

Comment: @WiloryLu We say that $f(x)$ has order (of infinitesimal) $n$ at $x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)/x^n$ is finite and nonzero. For instance $\sin x$ has order $1$ (at $0$) and $1-\cos x$ has order $2$, because $\lim_{x\to0}(1-\cos x)/x^2=1/2$. The order corresponds to the first power with nonzero coefficient in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: So, it comes from Taylor expansion, I think I have to search more about this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Without $\cos (3x)-\cos (2x)$ in the denominator you can  use rationalzation to see that the limit is $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$. Since $\cos (3x)-\cos (2x) \to 0$ through negative values the given limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: Why? $\cos(3x)-\cos(2x)$ is negative around $0$ and vanishes in $0,$ so the limit should be $-\infty$

Comment: @enzotib You are right. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @WiloryLu After rationaliztion use the facts that  $\frac {\sin x }x \to 1$ and  $\frac {\tan x} x =\frac {\sin x} x \frac 1 {\cos x} \to (1)(1)=1$ .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Limit is finite if it is $+\sin x$ in the question**

$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3 + \tan x}- \sqrt{3 + \sin x}}{x(\cos 3x - \cos 2x)}$$

Let us use
$$
\sin z= z-z^3/6+\ldots, \cos z=1-z^2/2+\ldots, \tan z= z+z^3/3$, (1+z)^{k}=1+kz+\ldots
$$
if $|z|$ is very small.
Then $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sqrt{3}[(1+\frac{1}{6}\tan x)-(1+\frac{1}{6} \sin x)]}{x(-9x^2/2+4x^2/2)}$$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5x^3}\frac{1}{6} [(x+x^3/3)-(x-x^3/6)]=\frac{-1}{10\sqrt{3}}$$